# Determine missing values based on lagged grouped values

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I need to fill missing values based on previous and/or forward values, based on grouping. I would like to accomplish this using dplyr (although data.table solutions will also be welcomed).

Sample data:

```
testing <- tibble(key = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20),
                  year = c(15,15,16,16,17,17,15,15,16,16,17,17),
                  name = c("abc","abc","","","dfg","dfg",
                          "","","nmm","nmm","",""),
                  is_name = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))

     key  year  name is_name
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     10    15   abc       1
2     10    15   abc       1
3     10    16             0
4     10    16             0
5     10    17   dfg       1
6     10    17   dfg       1
7     20    15             0
8     20    15             0
9     20    16   nmm       0
10    20    16   nmm       0
11    20    17             0
12    20    17             0
```

I want to fill missing names (`name`) in a way that if the previous `year` of the same `key` is marked as `is_name==1`, than fill the missing with it.
So an output can be:

```
     key  year  name is_name name_new
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>    <chr>
1     10    15   abc       1      abc
2     10    15   abc       1      abc
3     10    16             0      abc
4     10    16             0      abc
5     10    17   dfg       1      dfg
6     10    17   dfg       1      dfg
7     20    15             0         
8     20    15             0         
9     20    16   nmm       0      nmm
10    20    16   nmm       0      nmm
11    20    17             0         
12    20    17             0
```

I tried to use `lag` and `leap`, but it didn't move beyond the group (`key`)properly.

Thanks!

Comment: `na.locf` from the `zoo`-package is what you are looking for

Comment: @Jaap I have prepared an answer using `na.locf`, then saw your comment. Should I post it or do you intend to post your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

testing <- testing %>%
           arrange(key, year) %>%
           mutate(name = ifelse(name == "", NA, name),
                  is_name = ifelse(is_name == 0, NA, is_name)) %>%
           group_by(key) %>%
           mutate(newname = ifelse((is.na(name) & na.locf(is_name, na.rm = FALSE) == 1), na.locf(name, na.rm = FALSE), name),
                  is_name = ifelse(is.na(is_name),0,is_name))
```

Comment: What I need, and I'll edit it in my question presently, is exactly that, but based on a condition from the previous group - i.e., only if `is_name==1` than I want to do this.

Comment: I updated my answer with a change that may work to provide that functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Rows 9 and 10 are NAs now, but they should be with values.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a change to the newname mutate that I think should handle that.